# Opening a shared file in C++ without root previliges

Tags: c++, linux, samba

I am working on a Red-Hat machine without root prevliges.
I have some shared files that I can access using `smb://` with username and password. Since I don't have root previliges, I can't mount the share (or at least, I haven't been able to find out how).

What I need is to open the file for reading\writing from a C++ code.
Is there any way to do so?

Comment: If you can't access the file with `cat`, `file` or some other command line tool, then you won't be able to bypass that by writing code in C or C++, assembler, python or any other language (aside from hacking through security holes in the OS, but I don't believe that's easy, and if I did know how to do that, I certainly wouldn't post it here). You could perhaps use `smbclient` to mount it (e.g. in your home directory or /tmp or something). If that's not an option, it's time to talk to whoever gives access to those files...

Comment: @Mats I can access the files using `smbclient` but if I try to use `smbount` I get error command not found

Comment: The commonly accepted, modern way of mounting a SMB share is not to use `smbmount` but `mount -t cifs`. But of course, if you do not have `sudo` capabilities, this will fail all the same. No superuser rights, no mounting and unmounting. You're without luck there.

Comment: So, I can access the files using `smbclient` and also via File Browser, but there is no way to access them from a C\C++ code??

Answer (score 0):

you can use [libsmbclient](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages/libsmbclient.7.html) library to do normal file access like smbc_open, smbc_fstat, smbc_lseek, smbc_read.